# Cannot read property 'find' of undefined in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this object `valuesColors` that I use in a function

```
export class CountryEnvelopeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  valuesColors: [
      {
        key: "<75%";
        color: "#00965E";
      },
      {
        key: ">=75%&<90%";
        color: "#ff9933";
      },
      {
        key: ">90%";
        color: "#E61D00";
      }
    ];
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  getColor(value) {
    console.log(this.valuesColors);
    let element = this.valuesColors.find(elm => {
      return elm.key == value;
    });
    return element.color;
  }
}
```

In HTML, inside a loop I change style using `getColor` function

```
<div [style.background-color]="getColor(title.value)" class="badge circle-indicator"></div>
```

I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `valuesColors = you array` ?

Comment: you probably meant to set the variable inside constructor?

Comment: Also , your array has syntax errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `=` instead of `:` :

```js
valuesColors = [
      {
        key: "<75%",
        color: "#00965E"
      },
      {
        key: ">=75%&<90%",
        color: "#ff9933"
      },
      {
        key: ">90%",
        color: "#E61D00"
      }
    ];
```

`:` defines an object type whereas `=` gives it some value. (be aware of the `,` instead of the `;` in your array)

Answer (score 2):

so `:` ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)) is used to set the type of the variable , So it must have been `valuesColors:Array = your array`
And your objects must be terminated by `,` not ';'
Your array must look something like this :

```
valuesColors = [
{
  key: "<75%",
  color: "#00965E",
},
{
key: ">=75%&<90%",
color: "#ff9933",
},
 {
key: ">90%",
color: "#E61D00",
 }
];
```

demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyo9q2
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think that `this` is referencing the `getColor` method in this case. Does it still happen if you instead write it as `getColor = (value) => {...}`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind your method to your class if you are calling it from another context. You could do this in your constructor:

```
constructor() {
    this.getColor = this.getColor.bind(this);
}
```

That way, when something else calls your method, your use of `this` within `getColor` is preserved and will have access to your class property.